# Triangle not rendering in GLFW3

Tags: c, opengl, glfw

I recently downloaded GLFW3 since it's better than GLUT from what I heard. I managed to get a window to display and change the clear colors but I cannot figure out why I'm not rendering anything in my draw calls. In this case, it's a triangle.  I'm running this on XCode 9.2 and this is the code I have right now:

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLCOREARB
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

static const GLfloat vertex_buffer_data[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    GLuint VertexBufferID;
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if ( !glfwInit() )
    {
        return -1;
    }

#ifdef __APPLE__
    /* We need to explicitly ask for a 3.2 context on OS X */
    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
#endif

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 400 , 400, "Hello World", NULL, NULL );
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glGenBuffers(1, &VertexBufferID);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex_buffer_data), vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    //Edit in
    **program = initShaders(VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE);**

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        //set clear color
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        //clear window
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear the buffers
        //Draw
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBufferID);
        //got error 0x502 on line below
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

        //Edit in
        **glUseProgram(program);**

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

It's probably a minor mistake but I can't see it.

Edit: Okay shaders are **required** here from what I'm told. I don't know how I got away with it in GLUT. I guess it was an older version. So here are the shader programs I'm using.

```
"#version 330 core\n"
"layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;\n"
"   gl_Position.w = 1.0;\n"
"}\n";

"#version 330 core\n"
"out vec3 color;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   color = vec3(1, 0, 0);\n"
"}\n";
```

I should also mention that I've been following this tutorial for help as well. http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/

As for errors, I found an error in `glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);` as code 502, where it apparently means GL_INVALID_OPERATION, which I don't know what that means in this case.

Comment: If that's OpenGL 3.2/3.3, then don't you have to use shaders?

Comment: What does `glGetError()` return?

Comment: You explicitly requested a OpenGL 3 core profile. That by design does not work without a user-specified shader program.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you have to use a named **[Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object)**, when you use a core profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The 2nd parameter of [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml) is the target type of the buffer and not the named buffer object itself**. `glBufferData` uses the named buffer object which is bound to the specified target:

```
glBufferData(
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,            // GL_ARRAY_BUFFER instead of VertexBufferID
    sizeof(vertex_buffer_data),
    vertex_buffer_data,
    GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

---

If you want to use a [OpenGL Core profile context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context#Context_types), then you have to use a [shader program](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader), this is not optional.
Further **you have to create a named [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object), because the default vertex array object (0) is not present in core profile context**.

The modern way of rendering in OpenGL, would be to use a [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) program.

If you don't want to use use a shader program, than you have to use a compatibility context and you have to define the array of vertex data using the deprected way by [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml) and you have to enable the client-side capability for vertex coordinates by [`glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY )`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml).

```
glfwWindowHint (GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, 
    GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE); // instead of GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE

.....

glGenBuffers(1, &VertexBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
    sizeof(vertex_buffer_data), vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW); 

.....

glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBufferID);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)0); 
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
```